# Storing image files, psd files, ai files, flash in subversion

Tags: svn, version-control, image

Can I store large amounts of image files in subversion. My designers usually create these designs and store them anywhere on their pc and there's no system. Can I store the files in an svn repository. That way I can also protect my data against unauthorized access and its also easier to archive.

What are your comments and is there any better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can store whatever you want in an SVN repository. There are no restrictions on file types or anything.

Comment: I know I can, but can subversion handle large files easily? Thanks!

Comment: By large files, I want to store around 2000-3000 files ranging from 50 kb to 2-3 mb.

Comment: Yes, it can handle it just fine. (It will act as a binary final and SVN won't try to run any diffs on it)

Answer (score 4):

I would use Subversion over Git for binaries. Git has no locking given its distributed nature, which is a problem for binary files, when conflicts arise from 2 or more people updating the same file, then attempting a merge. Since your also concerned about security, Subversion has granular ACLs so you can lock down specific folders to your designers.

I would also not recommend Git for graphic designers. Git is fine for programmers, but for designers who just want to "save a file", its way to complex. Tortoise SVN for Subversion is easy to use for the non-programmer types.

Answer (score 3):

You can but it's not made for it. Git, SVN are made to manage text with line return (source code).

Other than that their can't make a diff so every time you commit a psd git is going to save it completely. You repository is going to grow very fast.

Take a 150mb PSD, say the designer change it 5 times and commit it each time, you end up with a repository of 750Mb! The problem is even worst with git where you need to download the all repository with the complete history locally.

So it's going to work, but it's certainly not the right tool for large bitmap file where you want to control history (certainly with different file name) and sync independently.

Answer (score 2):

We stored thousands of images in SVN. And when you want to synchronize for the first time it takes long hours, sometimes a day -in a 100MBit network-. Once completed the synch. operation then it works quite well.

This is my experience. I don't know what is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use "git" which will give you a local repository as well. The advantage is that you can "check in" temporarily on your local box without transferring large files to the server. Once your designers have the final product they can "push" it to the master repository.

Comment: It sounds like from his comment on webdestroya's [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846743/storing-image-files-psd-files-ai-files-flash-in-subversion/2846746#2846746) that he needs to handle large files though, and git is pretty famously bad at that (hence the work on [git-bigfiles](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/git-bigfiles))

Comment: I was just pointing to the alternatives to SVN. Even though git may be slower (I tried <10mb files - work just fine) it is still may be faster depending on the workflow by saving on uploading time.